# Equivalent of __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64 in Rust (addition with carry)

Tags: rust

There's no much information about `__builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64`, only I coud find is this: https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/adxintrin_8h_source.html

It looks like __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64 returns the carry of the addition of 2 u64 numbers as a u8. While I could implement this in Rust, would be nice to have the fast version of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably the [`u64::overflowing_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.56.1/std/primitive.u64.html#method.overflowing_add) function (which exists for `u64` and all other primitive integer types):

```rust
let x: u64 = 0x0123456789abcdef;
let y: u64 = 0xfedcba9876543212;

let (sum, carry) = x.overflowing_add(y);
// sum = 1, carry = true
```

This function returns a tuple with the resulting sum and the carry bit (as a `bool`), and is implemented using the [`add_with_overflow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/intrinsics/fn.add_with_overflow.html) compiler intrinsic, so it should be very fast.

---

If you need to take a carry value as input, you can (as you mentioned in a comment) use the nightly-only [`u64::carrying_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.56.1/std/primitive.u64.html#method.carrying_add). It's just [implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cc946fcd326f7d85d4af096efdc73538622568e9/library/core/src/num/uint_macros.rs#L1538-L1544) in terms of two `overflowing_add` operations, though, and you can just use these instead on stable Rust if you need it:

```rust
impl u64 {
    pub const fn carrying_add(self, rhs: u64, carry: bool) -> (u64, bool) {
        // note: longer-term this should be done via an intrinsic, but
        //   this has been shown to generate optimal code for now, and
        //   LLVM doesn't have an equivalent intrinsic
        let (a, b) = self.overflowing_add(rhs);
        let (c, d) = a.overflowing_add(carry as u64);
        (c, b || d)
    }
}
```

Comment: the overflowing_add does not permit me to specify a carry when adding, so it's not exactly what I need :c

Comment: it looks like `carrying_add` does that but it's nightly only

Comment: @Rafaelo Good point! Though if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cc946fcd326f7d85d4af096efdc73538622568e9/library/core/src/num/uint_macros.rs#L1538-L1544) for `carrying_add`, you'll see that it's just implemented in terms of two `overflowing_add` calls, and the comment claims that this does generate optimal code (when building with `--release`, I assume).